# Error with pyexiv2. How to apply metadata to jpg image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, exif, pyexiv2

I am writing a python3-based script designed to automate the process of applying geo-tags to .jpg images based on extracted EXIF metadata.

PIL is used to open images and read the EXIF metadata and pyexiv2 is used to apply geo-tags to the .jpg images.

The code for the applying geotags is shown here:

```
# Convert decimal coordinates to degrees, minutes, seconds
def to_degree(value, loc):
    if value < 0:
        loc_value = loc[0]
    elif value > 0:
        loc_value = loc[1]
    else:
        loc_value = ""
    abs_value = abs(value)
    deg =  int(abs_value)
    t1 = (abs_value-deg)*60
    min = int(t1)
    sec = round((t1 - min)* 60, 5)
    return (deg, min, sec, loc_value)

# Apply geotags to photos based on converted latitude and longitude
def apply_geotags(photo, lat, lng):
    # Convert coordinates into degrees, munutes and seconds
    lat_deg = to_degree(lat, ["S", "N"])
    lng_deg = to_degree(lng, ["W", "E"])                
    print(lat_deg)
    print(lng_deg)

    # Error here:
    # AttributeError: module 'pyexiv2' has no attribute 'Rational'
    exiv_lat = (pyexiv2.Rational(lat_deg[0]*60+lat_deg[1],60),pyexiv2.Rational(lat_deg[2]*100,6000), pyexiv2.Rational(0, 1))
    exiv_lng = (pyexiv2.Rational(lng_deg[0]*60+lng_deg[1],60),pyexiv2.Rational(lng_deg[2]*100,6000), pyexiv2.Rational(0, 1))
    print(exiv_lat)
    print(exiv_lng) 

    # Error here:
    # AttributeError: module 'pyexiv2' has no attribute 'ImageMetadata'
    metadata = pyexiv2.ImageMetadata(photo)
    metadata.read()

    metadata["Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLatitude"] = exiv_lat
    metadata["Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLatitudeRef"] = lat_deg[3]
    metadata["Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLongitude"] = exiv_lng
    metadata["Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLongitudeRef"] = lng_deg[3]
    metadata["Exif.Image.GPSTag"] = 654
    metadata["Exif.GPSInfo.GPSMapDatum"] = "WGS-84"
    metadata["Exif.GPSInfo.GPSVersionID"] = '2 0 0 0'

    metadata.write()
```

I am encountering several errors all related to pyexiv2 including

```
AttributeError: module 'pyexiv2' has no attribute 'Rational'
```

and

```
AttributeError: module 'pyexiv2' has no attribute 'ImageMetadata'
```

Any other recommendations for libraries that can apply/update metadata for .jpg images would also be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a missing dependency to me.

Comment: Do you know which one?

Comment: No, if I did I would leave an answer. My comment was meant to help you find the answer on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misread the documentation of pyexiv2 or you mistype the package name when installing with `pip`. The example on the [github page](https://github.com/LeoHsiao1/pyexiv2#usage) does not mention `ImageMetadata` or `Rational` classes. It only modify a dictionary.

**Edit**:
@psf highlights to me a package with a different name but using the same import [py3exiv2](https://pypi.org/project/py3exiv2/). In this package, I cannot find any `Rational` class to import but there is a class `fractions.Fraction` for [exif metadata](https://python3-exiv2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=Rational#pyexiv2-exif).

Comment: This one does and has the missing function: https://pypi.org/project/py3exiv2/
unfortunateley, both are imported the same way.